# Finding out the n of the element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, count, integer

I have a bunch of divs.

```
<div id="container">

  <div><a>One</a></div>
  <div><a>Two</a></div>
  <div><a>Three</a></div>
  <div><a>Four</a></div>

</div>
```

I have to find out, using Javascript and jQuery, in what div the **a** element has been clicked.

Must return an **integer**, based on in which *div* the **a** element has been clicked *(first, second, third or fourth)*.

Answer (score 3):

```
var divs = $('#container').on('click', 'a', function() {
   alert(divs.index(this.parentNode));
}).children('div');
```

Comment: Upvoting the other answer for sticking to jQuery

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent) to get the `div` from the `a`, and then use [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index) to get the position among its siblings..

```
$('#container a').click(function(){
   var self = $(this),
       clickedDiv = self.parent(),
       index = clickedDiv.index();

   alert(index); // first is 0, second is 1 etc...
});
```

---

The not-so-verbose syntax would be

```
$('#container a').click(function(){
   var index = $(this).parent().index();

   alert(index); // first is 0, second is 1 etc...
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Much obliged!

Answer (score 0):

Native JavaScript implementation using [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), [`.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.querySelectorAll) and [`.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener).

If there is only one `<a>` per `<div>`

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call( // for each
    document.querySelectorAll('#container a'), // <a> in #container
    function (elm, idx, arr) { // get it's info (index etc.) then
        elm.addEventListener('click', function () {console.log(idx);}, false);
            // make clicking it log it's index
    }
);
```

or if there are many `<a>`s per `<div>`

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call( // for each
    document.querySelectorAll('#container div'), // <div> in #container
    function (elm, idx, arr) { // get it's info (index etc.) then
        Array.prototype.forEach.call( // loop over each
            elm.querySelectorAll('a'), // <a> in that <div>
            function (a_elm, a_idx, a_arr) { // and
                a_elm.addEventListener('click', function () {console.log(idx);}, false);
                    // make clicking it log the index of the <div>
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Note logged indices will start from `0` for the 1st.